# Integrate the derivative of dirac

Tags: integration, solution-verification, dirac-delta

I am trying to compute
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\delta(t)}{dt} dt=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\delta(t)-\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty}\delta(t)=0-0=0$$

Is that valid?

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: Delta function is not a function in a conventional sense, it doesn’t have a “limit at a point”. And the whole thing of integrating a derivative of generalized functions over real line looks rather weird.

Comment: even if you put in a real function instead of $\delta(t)$ take $e^{-t^2}$

Comment: The proper way to interpret this is $\delta'(1(\cdot)) \equiv -\delta(1'(\cdot)) = \delta(0(\cdot)) = 0 $

Comment: @NinadMunshi Is $1(\cdot)=\cdot $ or is it a function like $1(x)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash the second notation is more accurate, it is not meant to be the identity. I tried to find a good notation to denote $1$ as a function for the functional i.e. $1(x) = 1$

Comment: The derivative $\delta'$ is what physics calls a "dipole".  It is zero except at the origin, but at the origin it is an impulse of size $+1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ immediately followed by an impulse of size $-1/\sqrt{2\pi}$.  So the two impulses cancel when we integrate, and we get result $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the language of distribution theory the first expression could be interpreted as
$\langle \delta', \mathbf 1 \rangle,$
where $\mathbf 1$ is the function having value $1$ everywhere. This expression is valid since $\delta'$ has compact support and $\mathbf 1$ is smooth.

By the definition of derivatives of distribution we have
$$
\langle \delta', \mathbf 1 \rangle
= -\langle \delta, \mathbf 1' \rangle
= -\langle \delta, \mathbf 0 \rangle
= 0,
$$
since the derivative of $\mathbf 1$ of course is the zero function.

So your result is valid although the calculation is not mathematically rigorous.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is correct and reasoning not totally out of line, but to make things a bit more rigorous, you might want to get rid of the derivative before integrating.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \delta '(x) dx$

$u=f(x). dv=\delta'(x)$

$du=f'(x). v= \delta(x)$

$G(f)=f(x)\delta(x)|_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)\delta(x) dx=-f'(0)$

Suppose $f(x)=e^x$.

Then $G(e^x)=0-0-1=-1. $

In your case $f(x)=1$, so $G(1)=0.$

Generally, you want to do whatever substitutions you can to the arguments of integration before applying the principle that $\int f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0).$